# jQuery validate - group inputs with similar rules

Tags: jquery-validate

I am using jquery validate, to validate a submitted form. The form has three input fields which have same rule i.e., only number and required - true. Can i write a single rule for all the three inputs say -

```
     rules: {
                "depository.startDate":{
                    required:true,
                    digits:true
                },
                "depository.endDate":{
                    required:true,
                    digits:true
                },
                "depository.port":{
                    required:true,
                    digits:true
                }
            },
```

to

```
 rules: {
            "depository.startDate, depository.port, depository.endDate ":{
                required:true,
                digits:true
            }
        },
```

I tried but its not working, any other way i can get this validation work.

--
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the built-in `rules()` method to add rules.  [See documentation.](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules)

Note:  You **must** call this method *after* you call `.validate()`, and it must be combined with an `.each()`.

[jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kSFKE/5/)

HTML:

```html
 <input type="text" name="depository.startDate" />
 <input type="text" name="depository.endDate" />
 <input type="text" name="depository.port" />
```

jQuery:

```js
$('#form').validate({
    // your other options
});

// the following method must come AFTER .validate()
$("input[name*='depository']").each(function() {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true,
        digits: true
    });
});
```

This method can also be very useful when you are dynamically adding fields to your form.

The following to combine with custom `messages:`.  Note that the format is slightly different than when adding rules as options within `.validate()`...

```js
$("input[name*='depository']").each(function() {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true,
        digits: true,
        messages: {
            required: "Required input",
            digits: "Only digits please"
        }
    });
});
```

---

Alternatively, you can use a `class` instead, but for it to work properly, you must also combine it with an `.each()`...

[jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kSFKE/4/)

HTML:

```html
 <input type="text" class="myclass" name="depository.startDate" />
 <input type="text" class="myclass" name="depository.endDate" />
 <input type="text" class="myclass" name="depository.port" />
```

jQuery:

```js
$('form').validate({
    // your other options
});

// the following method must come AFTER .validate()
$('form').find('.myclass').each(function() {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true,
        digits: true
    });
});
```