# jQuery validation don't work after add and input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I've a form where I have rows to an table manually.
This row need and input (required) and have two select...

The problem is, if I add more than one row the submit validation for the table don't work for the second (and subsequent rows)...

Javascript code:

```
$('#classAdd').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                //trainingAction.addRow(schoolGroups[0].schoolGroupId, -1, '');
                //add one line
                $('#classes > tbody:last').append('<tr><td><input class="required datepicker classStartDate" name="classStartDate" /></td>'+
                    '<td><select class="classSchoolGroupId"></select></td>'+
                    '<td><select class="classSchoolId"></select></td>'+
                    '<td><a href="#" class="none classRemove"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a></td></tr>');

                var last = $('#classes tr:last');
                var csgi = last.find('.classSchoolGroupId');
                var csi = last.find('.classSchoolId');
                var input = last.find('.classStartDate');


                //append values
                trainingAction.appendArrayToSelect(csgi, schoolGroups, 'schoolGroupId', 'schoolGroupName', -1);
                //append values
                trainingAction.appendArrayToSelect(csi, schoolGroups[0].getSchools(), 'Value', 'Text', -1);

                //add event
                trainingAction.schoolGroupChange(csgi);

                //rebind datepicker
                helpers.bindDatepicker();
                //rebind validators    
                $('form').validate();
                $(input).rules('add', {
                    required: true
                });

                //rebind remove button
                trainingAction.removeClass();
            });
```

I try the code above like the suggested here ([jQuery validate - group inputs with similar rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14053245/jquery-validate-group-inputs-with-similar-rules)).

Another snippet that I try and don't work (based on this post [jquery validation rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330573/jquery-validation-rules))

```
$('form').validate({
    rules:{
        classStartDate: {
            required:true
        }
    }
});
```

Any suggestion to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**:
jQuery version: 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you duplicate with the same name on the input only the first one is validated, you need to add the brackets to the name like this

```
<input class="required datepicker classStartDate" name="classStartDate[]" />
```

And the javascript

```
$('form').validate({
    rules:{
        "classStartDate[]": {
            required:true
        }
    }
});
```

hope i can help in something